# E966 `nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component

Tags: nlp

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')

def train_model(train_data):
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last = True)
    
    for _, annotation in train_data:
        for ent in annotation['entities']:
            ner.add_label(ent[2])
            
    
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(10):
            print("Statring iteration " + str(itn))
            random.shuffle(train_data)
            losses = {}
            index = 0
            for text, annotations in train_data:
                try:
                    nlp.update(
                        [text], 
                        [annotations], 
                        drop=0.2,
                        sgd=optimizer,
                        losses=losses)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
                
            print(losses)
```

```
train_model(train_data)
```

Error:

[E966] `nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component. Expected string, but got <spacy.pipeline.ner.EntityRecognizer object at 0x7ff8f26c3a50> (name: 'None').

- If you created your component with `nlp.create_pipe('name')`: remove nlp.create_pipe and call `nlp.add_pipe('name')` instead.
- If you passed in a component like `TextCategorizer()`: call `nlp.add_pipe` with the string name instead, e.g. `nlp.add_pipe('textcat')`.
- If you're using a custom component: Add the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components / factories) to your custom component and assign it a name, e.g. `@Language.component('your_name')`. You can then run `nlp.add_pipe('your_name')` to add it to the pipeline.

How do I train the model?